# How to integrate RTIR with Nagios

Tags: nagios, request-tracker

I have installed RTIR with RT v 3.8.4. I have also Nagios installed for monitoring a number of our servers. Now, in the download website of RTIR (http://www.bestpractical.com/rtir/features.html), it says

> "We've already built integrations with ArcSight, Nagios, and other
>   software"

But I couldn't find any documents on it. Even I found some Nagios plugin which sends alert to RTIR, but I'm not sure whether it will properly fill all the fields of RTIR incident report like IP address of the affected server or not. So I would like a detailed explanation on this or may be a good documentation link will help.

Comment: http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/AutoCloseOnNagiosRecoveryMessages